# Trying to append a list of names while using a range operator

Tags: arrays, powershell, append, operators

Trying to do something like this:

```
$BaseCompName = ProdServer-
$CompNameSuffix = 1..45
$ServerName = "$BaseCompName" + "$CompNameSuffix"
```

The idea would be to generate a list - in RAM, TXT file or CSV file - that would look something like

```
ProdServer-1
ProdServer-2
ProdServer-3
...
ProdServer-45
```

From that list, I'd use `ForEach`, or something of the like, to ping them via `Test-Connection` or something like that and then add that data to a file or whatever we'd be doing with the data at the time.

I'm not really sure how to construct this.  I've seen example of people using the range operator to ping a mess of IPs but, whenever I try to cobble together something from that, it just fails miserably.  I rearrange things and I see more and more errors.  Now, I'm lost and everything's starting to look the same.

My latest attempt:

```
$CompName = 1..45
$Servers = "PRODSERVER-" + $CompName
ForEach ($Server in $Servers) { 
    Test-Connection -ComputerName $Server -Count 1 }| Export-Csv 'C:\Users\SucksAtPowerShell\Desktop\ips.csv' -NoTypeInformation }
```

As mentioned before, that breaks...

```
Test-Connection : Testing connection to computer 'PRODSERVER-1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 
    19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45' failed: The requested 
    name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found
    At line:4 char:5
    +     Test-Connection -ComputerName $Server -Count 1 }
    +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (PRODSERVER-1 2 ... 41 42 43 44 45:String) [Test-Conne
      ction], PingException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TestConnectionException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestConnectionCommand
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not iterating over each array element. When cast as a string your array is just getting joined with each element separated by a space.

There are multiple approaches to this but most involve processing the integer array inside a loop. Lets move the range operator into pipeline input for `ForEach-Object`

```
1..45 | ForEach-Object {
    $Server =  "PRODSERVER-$_"
    Test-Connection -ComputerName $Server -Count 1
} | Export-Csv 'C:\Users\SucksAtPowerShell\Desktop\ips.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Or something more in line to what you had before

```
$CompName = 1..45
$Servers = $CompName | ForEach-Object{"PRODSERVER-" + $_}
```

Comment: That worked out well!  I always seem to get confused with the `$_`.  Pipelines are cools but I still seem to have issues with constructing them on my own.